# Show that $T(JX,JY)+T(X,Y)=-\frac{1}{2}N_{J}(X,Y)$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential

Let $(M,J,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold where $j$ is tensor field of type $(1,1)$ satisfying $J^2=1$. Then we have the following 
$$T(JX,JY)+T(X,Y)=-\frac{1}{2}N_{J}(X,Y),$$for all $X,Y 
\in\chi{M}$, where $T$ denotes the torsion tensor.

Could someone please help me prove this result? 
I am trying to prove by using the definition of Nijenhuis tensor as following
$ N(JX,JY)=J^2[X,Y]+[JX,JY]-J[JX,Y]-J[X,JY]\\
           = [X,Y]+[JX,JY]-J[JX,Y]-J[X,JY]  $
$ T(X,Y)= \nabla_XY-\nabla_YX-[X,Y] .....(1)$\

and $T(JX,JY)=\nabla_{JX}JY-\nabla_{JY}JX-[JX,JY]....(2) $\
Ading (1) an (2) I coulnot get required result.So please help me how to proceed.

Comment: Which definition of the Nijenhuis tensor $N_J$ are you using?

Comment: @user10354138   I am using the definition $N_j(X,Y)=[JX,JY]+J^2[X,Y]-J[JX,Y]-J[X,JY]$ and using the relation $J^2=Id$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you found that relation? What you can prove (strongly relateded to almost complex structures on manifolds) is the following:

$\textbf{Claim}$: Let $(M,g,\nabla)$ be a Riemannian manifold endowded with a connection, and $J\in T^1_1(M)$ s.t. $J \circ J= -id_{T^1_1(M)}$ and $J$ compatible with the connection (i.e. $\nabla_X JY=J \nabla_X Y$), then
\begin{equation}
N_J(X,Y)= T_{\nabla}(X,Y) + JT_{\nabla}(JX,Y) +JT_{\nabla}(X,JY) - T_{\nabla}(JX,JY) 
\end{equation}
Proof. Expanding the RHS 
\begin{align*}
RHS =&\nabla_X Y - \nabla_YX -[X,Y]+ J \nabla_{JX} Y - J\nabla_Y JX -J[JX,Y]+ \\&+J\nabla_{X} JY - J\nabla_{JY} X -J[X,JY]- \nabla_{JX} JY + \nabla_{JY} JX +[JX,JY]\\ =&\nabla_X Y - \nabla_YX -[X,Y]+ J \nabla_{JX} Y +\nabla_Y X -J[JX,Y]+ \\&-\nabla_{X} Y - J\nabla_{JY} X -J[X,JY]- J\nabla_{JX} Y + J\nabla_{JY} X +[JX,JY]\\ =&\ -[X,Y]  -J[JX,Y]  -J[X,JY] +[JX,JY]\\ =& J^2[X,Y]  -J[JX,Y]  -J[X,JY] +[JX,JY]=N_J(X,Y)
\end{align*}

Not sure you can simplify the expression by some extra requirements to what you wrote down.

Comment: Thanking you sir very much. If you have no problem, then I request you to share your email for futher commmunication on this topic.